# Is using enum types for user interface functions a good idea?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I'm building a simple class that prints some text on the screen, and it has the possibility to change the colors of the text.

```
myclass a("this is the text");
a.setColor("green");
```

I'm still learning C++ and I recently got introduced to `enum` and thought I'd give it a try. I was wondering if it is a good practice to use `enum` types in interface functions like the above `setColor`?

What are the advantages or disadvantages of using `enum` classes in interface functions? Are there cases where they are more applicable than and are there case where they are bad to use?

What if I want to combine properties? E.g.

```
a.setAttribute("bold reverse");
```

*I don't know if* interface *is the correct term for what I want to describe: the functions that a user of my class would end up using.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, there are (at least) two advantages:

- No need to parse the string at run-time, leading to higher efficiency.  You can use an enum variable directly in a `switch` statement.
- An enum is (to some extent) self-documenting, the user of your code has to work hard to provide an invalid value.

One potential "disadvantage" is in the case where the colour string has come from e.g. run-time userinput (they've typed into a textbox or something).  You will need to parse this string and convert it into an enum.  But it's not really a disadvantage, because you'll need to do this anyway.  Best practice is for the user-interface logic to validate the string and convert to the enum at the earliest opportunity.

> What if I want to combine properties?

I can think of at least three options:

- Use multiple calls to `setAttribute`.
- Pass an array of attributes.
- Define each enum value to be a power-of-two, and then you can combine enums with `|`.

Comment: @romeovs: I don't think so.  Consequently, I'm less keen on that option.

Comment: I'm using `std::initializer_list<eColor>` to fix that!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using an `enum` in this case seems better than an actual string.

One clear advantage - strong typing.

If `setColor` accepts a `char*`, like in your case, you could do:

```
 a.setColor("horse");
```

which you can only detect as an error at runtime.

If `setColor` takes an `eColors` as parameter:

```
 a.setColor(eGreen);
 a.setColor(eRed);
```

would compile, but

```
 a.setColor(eHorse);
```

would not.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are definitely more explicit than strings for this case. As for the concatenation of values, you can use some bit fiddling to make this work. Set the values of your enum to increasing powers of two, then you can OR them together.

```
enum TextAttributes {
    Bold = 1,
    Italic = 2,
    Reverse = 4,
    StrikeThrough = 8,
    Underline = 16
};

TextAttributes attr = Bold | Reverse;
```

Comment: Using this method, I cannot use enum classes right? Meaning this is not strongly typed?

Comment: Correct. You couldn't use a switch with this approach.

Comment: @romeovs It is possible to use scoped enumerations: you can overload the bitwise operators for them. This *can* mean a lot of boilerplate, but can be refactored for easy reuse.